# MDL input type date placeholder conflict on firefox

Tags: css, material-design

I am having an issue when using the MDL (Material Design Lite) library with input date on firefox. It displays a "placeholder mask" for the user, and the result is a visual conflict with the label:

[image]

I follow some tutorials to do the following:

```
input[type=date]:not( :focus )::-webkit-datetime-edit-ampm-field,
input[type=date]:not( :focus )::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
input[type=date]:not( :focus )::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field,
input[type=date]:not( :focus )::-webkit-datetime-edit-millisecond-field,
input[type=date]:not( :focus )::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field,
input[type=date]:not( :focus )::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
input[type=date]:not( :focus )::-webkit-datetime-edit-second-field,
input[type=date]:not( :focus )::-webkit-datetime-edit-week-field,
input[type=date]:not( :focus )::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field,
input[type=date]:not( :focus )::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
  color: transparent;
}
```

However this fix the problem only for Google Chrome.

Any sugestions?

Thank you.